# Adding a row to the specific place in another data.frame

Tags: r

This is one of the row from df2,

```
       PERSON_ID EVENT LATERALITY BEHAV EventAge     DATE
198 10000002174  C569          9     3       64  19890413
```

I want to insert this row into df1 in a proper place,

```
          PERSON_ID   DOB_rev exact_dob       DATE       exact EVENT LATERALITY               BEHAV
     56 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes  4/13/1975         Yes   BC1          9 Malignant(Invasive)
     57 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1975 No_from_age   L_B          .                   .
     58 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1989 No_from_age   OV1          .                   .
     59 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1989 No_from_age   OV2          .                   .
     60 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1993 No_from_age DEATH          .                   .
     61 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes   6/8/1998         Yes   EPI          .                   .
```

which must be in the order of the "DATE" variable. so I want my output to be

```
          PERSON_ID   DOB_rev exact_dob       DATE       exact EVENT LATERALITY               BEHAV
     56 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes  4/13/1975         Yes   BC1          9 Malignant(Invasive)
     57 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1975 No_from_age   L_B          .                   .
     58 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes   19890413 No_from_age  C569          .                   .         
     58 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1989 No_from_age   OV1          .                   .
     59 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1989 No_from_age   OV2          .                   .
     60 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1993 No_from_age DEATH          .                   .
     61 10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes   6/8/1998         Yes   EPI          .                   .
```

I was thinkg various approaches, but I ended up taking way too complex route and failed to finish, such as taking 1 row from df2, try to add it into df1 and reorder by PERSON_ID and DATE. can anybody give me any advice to attack this problem?

Comment: Do you need help finding the right place to insert or just with the insertion? And do you really want mixed date formats like that? Seems like it will be hard to work with moving forward...

Comment: Ideally you need to design your data first in a way that it is independent from the order. this way you will just need to `rbind` it.

Comment: I was writing a for loop to tackle this intelligently but I think I will just rbind df1 and df2  and just sort by ID and then DATE column(after I change them to common format). This seems to be very dirty way and kinda disturb original df1 ordering.... but I cant come up with better idea

Comment: The code you provided doesn't allow `rbind` to work because `df1` and `df2` have different numbers of columns.

Answer (score 0):

This will work using `lubridate` (though it's not strictly necessary).

```
library(lubridate)
```

First read in the data:

```
lines = '      PERSON_ID EVENT LATERALITY BEHAV EventAge     DATE
 10000002174  C569          9     3       64  19890413'

df2 <- read.table(text = lines, header = T)

lines = 'PERSON_ID   DOB_rev exact_dob       DATE       exact EVENT LATERALITY               BEHAV
      10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes  4/13/1975         Yes   BC1          9 Malignant(Invasive)
      10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1975 No_from_age   L_B          .                   .
      10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1989 No_from_age   OV1          .                   .
      10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1989 No_from_age   OV2          .                   .
      10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes 10/13/1993 No_from_age DEATH          .                   .
      10000002174 4/13/1925       Yes   6/8/1998         Yes   EPI          .                   .'

df1 <- read.table(text = lines, header = T)
```

Change the date formats to be the same (`ymd` and `mdy` are from `lubridate`)

```
df1$DATE <- mdy(df1$DATE)
df2$DATE <- ymd(df2$DATE)
```

Merge, keeping all rows

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, all = T)
df <- df[with(df, order(PERSON_ID, DATE)), ]
```

Final output (changing `PERSON_ID` to character to match your output)

```
df$PERSON_ID <- as.character(df$PERSON_ID)
df
    PERSON_ID       DATE EVENT LATERALITY               BEHAV   DOB_rev exact_dob       exact EventAge
1 10000002174 1975-04-13   BC1          9 Malignant(Invasive) 4/13/1925       Yes         Yes       NA
2 10000002174 1975-10-13   L_B          .                   . 4/13/1925       Yes No_from_age       NA
3 10000002174 1989-04-13  C569          9                <NA>      <NA>      <NA>        <NA>       64
4 10000002174 1989-10-13   OV1          .                   . 4/13/1925       Yes No_from_age       NA
5 10000002174 1989-10-13   OV2          .                   . 4/13/1925       Yes No_from_age       NA
6 10000002174 1993-10-13 DEATH          .                   . 4/13/1925       Yes No_from_age       NA
7 10000002174 1998-06-08   EPI          .                   . 4/13/1925       Yes         Yes       NA
```